# Topological Thouless pumping

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, topological-insulators, topological-order

I can't understand why the number of electrons pumped per cycle of a quantum pump is protected topologically. [image]  As for me this number is an integer **in any case**, because the number of electrons in every potential well cannot be continuous.

Comment: What do you mean by "in any case"?

Comment: I mean you cannot get the fractional number of electrons in a well, I forgot to write that chemical potential does not coincide with the level of electron in a well

Comment: I still am missing your point. If you agree that the pumped charge is quantized then what is the distinction between "topological" or not? I will note though that the Thouless pump is much more general than this simple potential well picture, that is just an illustrative example.

Comment: Can we say that quantization of pumping charge follows from that every electron cannot have a fractional charge? you can pump  only entire electron or nothing

Comment: Yes, even in the most general formulation of the Thouless pump, the quantization is ultimately a consequence of the fact that electric charge is quantized, or equivalently the symmetry group for charge conservation is U(1).

Comment: All of this well defined as long as the bulk of the pump is gapped, therefore this number is topological invariant. But I can't understand what changes when the bulk of the pump isn't gapped, it seems that in this case we also can pump only integer number of electrons just becouse there is not any fractional part of electrons

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86885/discussion-between-phys-dag-and-dominic-else).